# Mounting ubuntu's root.disk in Windows 7

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-9.10, mount, ntfs, wubi

I've got Ubuntu 9.10 installed in an NTFS partition. After an update, I started getting kernel panics, so I need to reinstall it. But before I do that, I need to retrieve and backup my home directory. I believe Ubuntu's file system is packaged in the root.disk image. So how do I mount it in Windows?

Comment: Did you install Ubuntu on a NTFS-Partition (native installer), or in a NTFS-Partition (Wubi)?

Comment: I used Wubi....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know how to mount the / partition in Windows 7, but I would use an Ubuntu Live cd to boot and, within the live session, I would mount an external hard drive to do backup.

If you haven't an usb drive you could use the Ubuntu Live cd, then mount the Windows 7 disk and copy all your files inside that.

Hope that helps,

Regards

Comment: I would prefer not to drive downtown to pickup a blank disc. I don't have the LiveCD on me right now.

Comment: A blank cd? If you haven't that too, try googling for UNetbootin. ;) I found it veeeeeery useful in similar situations!